# .htaccess foobar.html -> foobar.php

Tags: .htaccess

i have to edit an existing web project. This project has only html pages and links to html pages. 
Ex. from foobar.html is a link to bar.html.
Now I have to edit several pages and change the url to bar.php.
I dont want to change every

Answer (score 2):

Put a [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) for each one you need to remap in your .htaccess file.

```
Redirect /junk.html   http://yoursite.com/junk.php   permanent
Redirect /junk2.html  http://yoursite.com/junk.php   permanent
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk), [python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) to edit/replace the strings your file. In this order ;)

(see: Unix or Cygwin)

Comment: unfortunately i dont have write access to all project files to edit them.

Comment: I don't understand: what do you have to change here exactly? There is a bunch of HTML-files which you can't edit but where you have to change the <a href>s?

Comment: I have to change some html files to php files. But i can't change the link to them.

Comment: Seems like Nathan has the solution for you.